# "Although, the causes of..." or "Although the causes"?

Tags: grammar, commas

I'm correcting something which my friend wrote. He wrote about incidents that had occurred while working in a mine, and stated that although the *cause* of each incident may have been different, they had in common a single reason: the workers did not follow the rules.

Here is the sentence:

> Although, the causes of each incident may have been different, the same common reason applies:...

I believe that placing a comma after *although* is incorrect. My friend believes that it is correct. Would you please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not ok. In an essay commas ought to be avoided in general [Edit: This is a ridiculous statement. I only meant they are often overused]. Furthermore, "Although," with that comma implies that he's contradicting something he just said. It sounds like he's reinforcing his thesis, so he definitely doesn't want to do that.

Comment: Can you cite a source for the statement "In an essay commas ought to be avoided in general"?

Comment: Haha, no, that was excessive. What I meant was "people often overuse commas in essays", that was my mistake. Good catch. I can't cite that either, that's just my empirical experience.

Comment: Gotcha, @McGurk! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Commas are disjunctive and do not suit well with conjunctions. Putting a comma after a conjunction is only acceptable if it is one of a pair of commas bracketing a parenthetical remark:

> <sup>OK</sup> Although, to be sure, the causes may have been different ...
>    <sup>∗</sup>  Although, the causes may have been different ...